# T-X and Magnet Scene

Tags: the-terminator-series

All right, so there seems to be a lot of Terminator 3 airings these last few weeks and I actually sat down to analyze things more than I had done in the past. For thoughts, I put this question forward.

Why, when the magnet affects anything metal does it not affect the T-X's inner mechanisms such as the spinning blade she uses to cut the magnet open? If the magnet was strong enough to attract the T-X and the gun, surely it would have attracted the spinner blade and so would not have allowed her to continue pursuing both John Connor and Kate Brewster.

[image]

Comment: Wait. You *willingly* watched Terminator 3 multiple times?

Comment: Granted, it IS the worst of the franchise, but Terminator is like Star Trek - even at its worst it's still somewhat entertaining.

Comment: I liked 3 better than Salvation, if only barely. Claire Danes and Terminatrix may have had something to do with that.

Comment: I'm entertained by bots (sorry...CYBERNETIC ORGANISMS) beating the crap out of each other. Sorry.

Comment: Terminator 3 isn't the worst by far...it's a little too humorous and breaks some rules, but it's an acceptable entry. I'm just glad there were no more entries after that.

Comment: I'm interested to learn why you've un-accepted my answer

Comment: Valorum: I came back and thought to myself that really, everyone has a good answer. Do you lose points if I do it? If so, I am truly sorry. I would hope that I may have your knowledge on other questions should I need them answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

According to the official [T3 : Rise of the Machines Novelisation](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Terminator_3_Rise_of_the_Machines.html?id=DU-hnoszGTMC) by David Hagberg, the Terminator-X has an [exoskeleton](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Series_T-X) comprised of crystalline ceramic laced with carbon. It does also contain a small amount of titanium (and as such, would be mildly para-magnetic) but obviously this isn't sufficient to cause it to stick to the particle accelerator:

> "Terminator turned as T-X came toward them, the cyborg's liquid metal
>   skin and clothing peeling back to reveal its **formidable battle chassis
>   armored with a crystalline ceramic that was interlaced with nano
>   fibers of carbon and titanium.**"

The mimetic alloy covering it, however clearly does have strong magnetic properties which is why it's attracted to the malfunctioning electro-magnet.

> Her endoskeleton began to vibrate like a horribly stretched violin
>   string, shrieking and squealing, as **the artificial liquid steel** that
>   was used to lubricate her mechanical joints was slowly forced through
>   her body and into the center of the magnetic field.

Comment: What I want to know is, why did the Air Force have a particle accelerator in a facility used for weapons reaserch?

Comment: Particle cannons. 'Nuff said.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatoli_Bugorski

Comment: So is it to say that the blade was probably not magnetic? That could be plausible.

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar - The T-X seems to have sufficient strength to move it despite the magnetic field. The main content of her skeleton is (non-magnetic) ceramic and (non-magnetic) carbon with just a smidge of (magnetic) titanium.